# ssh user has no root rights

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I've set up an ssh user and add the user to the sudo users.

But when I connect via ssh and want to install something with `apt-get install`I goth this error

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 2.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you forget `sudo` in front of the command?

Comment: What has it got to do with SSH?

Comment: I connect via ssh directly into a docker container

Answer (score 2):

To invoke sudo rights you need to prefix the command with `sudo` followed by a space.